# Continuity of limit of continuous functions implies uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

We know that uniform convergence of continuous functions implies the continuity of the limit. I'm wondering if the inverse is true: if a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ converges to continuous function $f$, then is it true that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

My attempt is that for any $x$ in the domain and $\epsilon$, there exists a $a$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\le|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)-f_n(a)|+|f_n(a)-f_n(x)|$. But I can't estimate the distance between $|f(a)-f_n(a)|$. Any tips ?

Comment: Tip: What you are trying to show is false. Further tip: Try to find a sequence $f_n (x) \to 0$ for which the convergence is not uniform. Last Tip: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem which gives some form of what you want.

Comment: @PhoemueX I can find a sequence of discontinuous functions such that its limit is constant zero, e.g., $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{4^n}\quad &x\in[0,1) \\ \frac{1}{2^n}\quad &x\in[1,2)\end{cases}$. Is ti still false for continuous function sequence ?

Comment: How about $f_n(x)=x/n$ for $x \in \mathbb R$. This sequence of functions goes to zero pointwise but not uniformly. As said above, Dini's theorem is the strongest result  regarding you question. The book Counterexamples in Analysis gives examples to show that no conditions of Dini's theorem can be removed.

Comment: @User8128 Oh, I see, the key condition is that the domain must be compact.

Comment: @Hua there is no single key condition. Each condition is key: the space must be compact, the sequence must be increasing (or decreasing) in $n$ for each fixed $x$, and the limit function must be continuous. You can't remove any one of these conditions. I can give an example of a sequence of functions satisfying any two of them (but not the third) and converging non-uniformly if you want.

Comment: @User8128 Yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Construct for $n\geq 1$ a continuous function $f_n$ for which $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n(1/2n)=1$ and $f_n(x)\equiv 0$ for $x\geq 1/n$.

Comment: Rugh. Oh, this is a example that fails my hypothesis and also the dini theorem, right ? because this sequence function does not satisfy the monotonicity requirement, right ?

Comment: Yes, it converges (pointwise) to the zero-function but there is no uniform upper bound for the difference. And Dini doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 3):

$f_n(x) = n^2x^n(1-x) \to 0$ pointwise in $[0,1].$ But note $f_n(1-1/n) = n^2(1-1/n)^n(1/n) \to \infty.$ Thus $\sup_{[0,1]}|f_n - 0|$ does not go to $0$ (far from it), so the convergence is not uniform.